# jQuery set input values does not show up

Tags: jquery

Inside the browser I see a value in the `#worktime` input element. e.g. `7,6`
This value gets set before by jQuery `$("#worktime").val("7,6");`

But when I look with firebug into this line of code I see no value:

`<input id="worktime" value="" readonly="">`

But under the DOM section in firebug I see for this element a value of `"7,6"`.

If I want to print the `#worktime` value with `alert` no value shows up.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Is it in all browsers, or just Firefox?

Comment: Can you demonstrate this with complete code or a live example?  How are you inspecting this in Firebug?  The value, if set after the page loads, won't be in the page source but will be in the DOM.

Comment: It is set as the property `value` of the DOM element, it won't be reflected in the attribute `value` in the html.

Comment: Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/YNDaD/

Comment: and how can i check if the `value` of the DOM element changes?

Comment: look at it's value property. `theel.value` or `$(theel).val()`

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is a very large difference between the value property and the value attribute. The value attribute contains the *default value* of the input, while the value property contains the *current value*. The default value can also be found in the `defaultValue` property. changing the value does not change the value attribute or the `defaultValue` property.